# News video/audio with transcripts (or consistent subtitles)

Tags: resources, listening

I sometimes watch the news on the [CCTV LIVE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8Wy9LXCapw) youtube channel to improve my listening comprehension. Sometimes they provide subtitles in Chinese, and sometimes they don't. This is fine if I'm just trying to get the gist of the stories, but I know from experience that I improve a lot faster when I can go back over difficult parts in detail (e.g., with a dictionary). This is hard to do if there aren't subtitles or transcripts available.

Is there any place to watch or listen to the news in Chinese that either provides transcripts or always subtitles everything (in Chinese)? If not the news, something analytical and non-fictional?

Comment: "legal report" occurring almost daily of approx. 27 min duration, http://tv.cctv.com/lm/jrsf/,
rfa: news reports (3-6 min) with full transcripts, iribworldservice Chinese: commentaries at bottom of page 
(10-12 min)with full transcripts http://parstoday.com/zh

Comment: @user6065 you should make that an answer, parstoday seems like exactly what is needed

Comment: How can I get transcripts of documentaries?

Comment: If you don't restrict the content to only news, you'd find a lot more videos, such as videos for traveling, movie synopsis, etc. They are, in my opinion, a lot more fun than news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you watch CCTV-4 (Chinese international). Many of its programs are subtitled in BOTH Chinese and English. Plus, its translation is professional and accurate.
However, these programs are mostly documentaries and shows. I've not found any news program with English subtitle in China.
EDIT: There is a Simplified Chinese subtitled news program on J5, a Hong Kong TV channel, called Putonghua Xinwen Baodao (Standard Mandarin News).

Comment: I don't _want_ English subtitles. I want _Chinese_ subtitles for news.

Comment: Sadly there are almost no Chinese news with subtitles. But I have found an exception: TVB J5 Mandarin News with Simplified Chinese subtitle. Check this Hong Kong TV channel for information.

Comment: Aurus, can you add that to your answer? It appears 普通話新聞報道 (which also has videos on youtube) fits what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have added this to my answer.